# Pandas: Groupby based on matching substring in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a list that has elements like:

```
emails= ['xyz.com', 'abc.com','def.com']
```

Now, I have a dataframe that looks like:

df:

```
UserID    Email_Address
U001      u001@abc.com
U002      u002@xyz.com
U003      u003@xyz.com
U004      u004@abc.com
U004      u005@def.com
U006      u006@def.com
U007      u007@def.com
```

I want to perform count on groupby based on substring where the substring is the elements from the list.

Hence, the output should look like:

```
abc.com     2
def.com     3
xyz.com     2
```

My current code:

```
for domain in list1:
    count = df.groupby( [df.Email_Address.str.find(domain)]).sum()
```

Comment: What is your question? What is wrong here or what is the output you're currently getting?

Comment: What is `list1` in your `for` loop?  You only tell us about `emails` list and `df` dataframe.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for get values by lists and aggregate by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
pat = '|'.join(emails)
s = df['Email_Address'].str.extract('('+ pat + ')', expand=False)
df1 = df.groupby(s).size().reset_index(name='Count')
print (df1)
  Email_Address  Count
0       abc.com      2
1       def.com      3
2       xyz.com      2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def mapf(x):
    if x[x.find('@')+1:] in emails:
        return x[x.find('@')+1:]

data['Email_Address'].apply(mapf).value_counts()
```

Function returns None when string not match with emails.So it counts just matching ones.

And output be like :

```
def.com    3
abc.com    2
xyz.com    2
Name: Email, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

To know the ocurrences of a specific value in a dataframe you can use:

```
len(df[df['Email_Address'] == your_value])
```

So I think you are looking for something like:

```
for domain in list1:
    len(df[df['Email_Address'] == domain])  # Save this value whatever you want
```